# How to animated/smooth scroll to div using scrolltop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone help me turn my code into one that will animate the scroll. I've been researching and trying to do it myself but I'm obviously not doing something correctly.

Here is my JS:

```
$(function() { //When the document loads
  $(".jrm-menu-whyus > a").bind("click", function() {
    $(window).scrollTop($("#menu-jrm").offset().top);
    return false;
  });
});
```

Thanks!

It works fine, just want to animate the scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery.animate():

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#menu-jrm").offset().top});
```

[jQuery.animate documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: hmm, didn't work. It actually stopped working and didn't scroll at all.

Comment: Okay got it working, it needed " " instead of ' ' for the ("html, body") Ill choose your answer when you update it :)  Thanks!!!

Comment: Agreed, but i say that I used " " for the menu-jrm so I thought hmmm, and it worked. Thanks again!